# Replacing Ubuntu with Kubuntu

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu, hard-drive

I had used Ubuntu for several years, and lately I got an error I wasn't able to access the OS at all, tried all solutions given here to solve the problem, but I wasn't lucky at all.
So I had to make the drive as external one, and tried to get the info, but also it wasn't accessible. Now I end up by formatting it, and Install Kubuntu (they mentioned it's light weight than Ubuntu), and what I have now is a laptop with hard disk partitioned into Kubuntu and something else, that didn't get the point behind shown in the image:
[image: Section Correspond to devices]

So my questions now:

1. what I have to do with this red error give( Could not enter folder /boot/efi)
2. Is there anyway to get back my info after I formatted it! (I checked testdesk) but badly I wasn't able to realized how to continue with it (if I may get a full guidance or something better)
3. My hard drive Is 1TB, and when installing Kubuntu it was recommended that I don't use it full, so now, my data are in the 462 GB Hard Drive, in what I may use the New Volume, and does it affect if I add files in it, would they be accessed normally?

Sorry if my questions are weird or silly.

Thanks for helping and assisting.

**Edit:**
[image]

Comment: You have to use the `ll` command instead of the `ls` command. `ll` is short for `ls -l`.

Comment: Edited again :)
I replaced images with the output of `ll`

Comment: The “error” in your first question is nothing to worry about. You shouldn’t be using Dolphin in your EFI partition. Your old Ubuntu installation is gone unless you use advanced tools to examine the underlying hardware. I don’t think Clonezilla will preserve anything that could be left at the lowest level but a complete dd clone will. If you post the output of lsblk it will tell us about “New Volume”. To access that storage space you probably just need to mount it somewhere convenient.

Comment: Kubuntu is not known for being "lightweight".

Comment: @PonJar
here is the output: ```NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  99.2M  1 loop /snap/core/10859
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   469G  0 part /media/roaasoloh/New Volume
├─sda2   8:2    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   462G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
```

Comment: Ok so New Volume is mounted at /media/roaasoloh which is not very convenient. Did you mount it there? You might want to mount it in your home directory. To make that permanent you will need to edit the /etc/fstab file. There are plenty of guides on the internet or answered questions on here that will help you do that. I don’t think you have any serious issues with this installation except perhaps the recovery of any important you may have lost from the old installation.

Answer (score 1):

If I do understand correctly, your Kubuntu installation works; you can open terminal, file manager, and firefox. If that is the case:

Right click on all of the choices under Devices section and see where they are mounted.

Use `sudo apt install krusader` to install a file manager named krusader. Type `sudo krusader` or

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
Comment[en_US]=
Exec=sudo krusader
GenericName[en_US]=
GenericName=
GenericName[en_US]=
Icon=krusader_blue
MimeType=
Name=krusaderasroot
Path=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

save what is above (Change the language options as you wish) as a file (with any name, here it is krusaderasroot, no extension) on desktop. Right-click on it and select 'Is an executable'. Click on it, and when it asks, enter your password.

Go to where all the partitions in the devices section are mounted, you will be able to perform any operation you want, including changing owner if necessary (Right click-Permissions -- if necessary, advanced permissions).

If you do not need it, do not change owners; most linux directories needs to be only owned by root. This just helps you, to see what is in a folder or partition, owned by root.

EFI is your boot partition. If you are booting in successfully, you do not need to mess with it. If you want to hide it, right click on it, and choose 'Hide' or any option you desire.

I suggest you do not install krusader to see what is in EFI partition, it is a boot partition you do not need to mess with (in your case). What you are seeing is not an error. You are not root when you are in dolphin file manager.

462 is your Kubuntu partition.
And I cannot see from here of course, but New Volume is probably an empty data partition.

If you want to save any data from it, **do not write anything on any partition**, use a recovery program on another computer by putting your disk as an external disk, or boot from a recovery ISO from USB and see what you can recover and what you want to recover, and of course **save what you want to recover on another disk**, not onto this one.

For recovery program options, there is not a single answer, a small research and trying 2-3 different ones will help.

Some of recovery programs have their ISOs to boot from, if they do not; you can boot from Kubuntu Install ISO, select try Kubuntu Option, and install the program to there.

For booting from ISOs, you can use a single or multiboot USB Option.

Reminding you that, trying to see what you can recover, and depends on how much data you are going to save can take many hours.

Comment: in fact I tried several softwares, but badly, all requires paying to be able to recover data, If I removed the hard disk,and set it as external one, and tried to make recovery, this won't affect the OS for me? I mean I can normally set it in the laptop and works fine?

Comment: You will not be writing anything to that disk. You will just copy some formatted data from it. Unfortunately, as most linux forums, Ask Ubuntu is not open-minded enough for me to suggest how not to pay for a software. Make your own research. Try testdisk, though it is not the best option.

Comment: I mentioned that I was trying it, but seriously I got confused with it, and didn't get a way to continue :( 
Thank you so much for assisting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if this helps you as an answer, but I will give it a try.

1. Switch to command line, if you try these things. It gives you a lot more information. Just start the terminal application. In case you are not familiar with it, the most important commands are: `cd <path>` = change directory, `cd .` = change to current directory (you don't need it, just for understanding), `cd ..` change to parent directory, absolute paths start with `/`, relative ones with `<child directory>` or `./<child directory>`, `ls` lists all files in a folder, `ll` all files with details.
2. Start clonezilla from a live-cd and make a backup of your system. It is rather self-explaining, just follow the instructions without understanding too much. Alternatively, you can use rsync to backup your data (see below).
3. This looks like a access rights problem. To display the access rights, type `ll`. You need to be sure that all files have to correct owner. Look up, what it has to be and change it with `chown [-R] <user>:<group> <file/folder>`, if needed. If it is part of the system, it should be `root:root` (user root : group root). Most files have the access rights drwxr-xr-x. owner can read, write, execute; group members read and execute; all others read and execute; Accessing a directory counts as execution. You can edit these with `chmod 755 <file>`. 755 sets rwxr-xr-x, 644 sets rw-r--r--, it is binary. You can use it differently, just look it up.
4. Start ubuntu in recovery mode. When the blue screen with the prompt is coming, start the network drivers. Then switch to root shell. There you should be able to access everything and repair everything. Here you can backup your data via rsync to an external device. i.e. `# rsync -ravutz /home /media/yourName/backupDirectory`. You can try to repair your installation in the root shell by

i.e.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thanks for your assist, I'll update my answer to show you what I got in a reply for number 1, regarding num.2, badly we don't have this live-cd!Is it possible to make a usb bootable for such thing!, and in fact I wouldn't like to reinstall ubuntu! or you mean this won't affect my current work?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please elaborate. Downvotig without it, is just unacceptable.

Comment: @R.K you can make a USB Stick bootable. Download stax iso and unpack it to a USB Stick. Then follow the Readme, which you find now on the USB Stick. After booting this USB Stick, install gparted and Clonezilla on it. Reinstall Ubuntu-desktop reinstalls only the desktop, not the system. All your files will be maintained.